# Want more elaborated description regarding this: Base Path Solution

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, zend-framework

The code below is from .htaccess file auto generated by the zf command. Description is given but for me it bounced.

```
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

Is it regarding the solution that when we are having a zend project on a shared hosting and want to resolve path to `index.php`? Please explain.